# WRT_8044 No data loaded for this target Informatica 10.2.0

Tags: oracle, session, workflow, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am running a task in workflow. I have 2 sources and I am able to fetch the no of records from it. But, unable to insert into target table. All the data types are fine.

I have attached the session log for the same.

I've double checked all the data types in all the transformations.

here's the mapping logic,

```
Source 1            \
Source 2    > EXP   /       JNR > UPD   >   TGT
```

Could anyone please point me out what I'm doing wrong?

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6014 Initializing session [s_m_MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE_LOAD] at [Tue Dec 17 09:50:22 2019].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6683 Repository Name: [TMnD_CRM_Prod]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6684 Server Name: [Integration_TMnD_CRM_Prod]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6686 Folder: [mASTRA_NEW]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6685 Workflow: [wf_MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE] Run Instance Name: [] Run Id: [397741]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6101 Mapping name: m_MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE_LOAD.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6964 Date format for the Session is [MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6708 Using configuration property [EnableDataEncryption,no]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6708 Using configuration property [StoreHAPersistenceInDB,no]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6703 Session [s_m_MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE_LOAD] is run by 64-bit Integration Service  [node01_prdeim], version [10.2.0 HotFix1], build [0819].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24091  Thread [MANAGER] has the ID [1].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24058  Running Partition Group [1].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24000  Parallel Pipeline Engine initializing.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MONITOR PETL_24091  Thread [MONITOR] has the ID [2].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24001  Parallel Pipeline Engine running.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24003  Initializing session run.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING PETL_24091  Thread [MAPPING] has the ID [3].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING CMN_1569    Server Mode: [UNICODE]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING CMN_1570    Server Code page: [ISO 8859-1 Western European]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TM_6151 The session sort order is [Binary].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TM_6156 Using low precision processing.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TM_6180 Deadlock retry logic will not be implemented.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TM_6187 Session target-based commit interval is [10000].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TM_6307 DTM error log disabled. 
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TE_7022 TShmWriter: Initialized
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING DBG_21694   jnr_MARKET_COVER_ORG_EXT Partition [0]: Index cache size = [178956970], Data cache size = [357913940]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TT_11098    The Joiner transformation [jnr_MARKET_COVER_ORG_EXT] is configured with the join algorithm: Nested-Loop.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TM_6007 DTM initialized successfully for session [s_m_MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE_LOAD]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    PETL_24033  All DTM Connection Info: [<NONE>].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24004  PETL_24004 Starting pre-session tasks. : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:22 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   PRE-SESS    PETL_24091  Thread [PRE-SESS] has the ID [4].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24027  PETL_24027 Pre-session task completed successfully. : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:22 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    PETL_24006  Starting data movement.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TM_6660 Total Buffer Pool size is 7298376 bytes and Block size is 268088 bytes.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    PETL_24091  Thread [READER_1_1_1] has the ID [5].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    DBG_21438   Reader: Source is [OLTPSMIS], user [SIEBEL]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16051  Source database connection [OLTPSMIS] code page: [MS Windows Latin 1 (ANSI), superset of Latin1]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16003  Initialization completed successfully.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_1_1    PETL_24091  Thread [TRANSF_1_1_1] has the ID [6].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    PETL_24091  Thread [READER_1_2_1] has the ID [7].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    DBG_21438   Reader: Source is [OLAPSMIS], user [tableau]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    BLKR_16051  Source database connection [TABLEAU] code page: [MS Windows Latin 1 (ANSI), superset of Latin1]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    BLKR_16003  Initialization completed successfully.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_2_1    PETL_24091  Thread [TRANSF_1_2_1] has the ID [8].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    PETL_24091  Thread [WRITER_1_*_1] has the ID [9].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8147    Writer: Target is database [MASTRAPROD], user [mastra], bulk mode [OFF]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8221    Target database connection [mAstra] code page: [MS Windows Latin 1 (ANSI), superset of Latin1]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8124    Target Table MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE :SQL INSERT statement:
INSERT INTO MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE(MARKET_ID,MARKET_NAME,WDCODE,POP_GROUP,DISTRICT,SUB_DISTRICT,PLAN_FLAG,ACTUAL_FLAG,TRANSDATE)  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8124    Target Table MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE :SQL UPDATE statement:
UPDATE MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE SET POP_GROUP = ?, DISTRICT = ?, SUB_DISTRICT = ?, PLAN_FLAG = ?, ACTUAL_FLAG = ?, TRANSDATE = ? WHERE MARKET_ID = ? AND MARKET_NAME = ? AND WDCODE = ?
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8124    Target Table MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE :SQL DELETE statement:
DELETE FROM MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE WHERE MARKET_ID = ? AND MARKET_NAME = ? AND WDCODE = ?
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8270    Target connection group #1 consists of target(s) [MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8003    Writer initialization complete.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16007  Reader run started.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    BLKR_16007  Reader run started.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    RR_4029 SQ Instance [SQ_S_ORG_EXT] User specified SQL Query [select wd.integration_id,mkt.name from s_org_ext wd,s_region mkt,s_Synd_Data b where wd.row_id=b.ou_ext_id and B.AREA_ID=mkt.row_id and  mkt.type_cd = 'BASE GOI']
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    RR_4049 RR_4049 SQL Query issued to database : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:22 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    RR_4029 SQ Instance [SQ_MAKKET_SERVICE_MODE_MASTER] User specified SQL Query [select a.BRANCH_CODE BRANCH, 
a.BASE_GOI_MARKET_ID MARKET_ID,
a.BASE_GOI_MARKET_NAME MARKET_NAME,
(case when a.BASE_GOI_POP_GROUP in ('2-5','<2') then '<5k'
when a.BASE_GOI_POP_GROUP in ('10-20') then '10-20k'
when a.BASE_GOI_POP_GROUP in ('5-10') then '5-10k'
when a.BASE_GOI_POP_GROUP in ('>1000','500-1000','100-500','51-100','21-50') then '21-50k'
else a.BASE_GOI_POP_GROUP end )POP_GROUP,
b.X_DISTRICT DISTRICT,b.X_SUB_DISTRICT SUB_DISTRICT,a.TYPE,
'Y' PLAN_FLG from TABLEAU.MAKKET_SERVICE_MODE_MASTER A, olap.w_regn_d b
where TO_CHAR(a.BASE_GOI_MARKET_ID)=b.X_MARKET_CODE
and A.PLAN_FLG is not null]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8005    Writer run started.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    RR_4049 RR_4049 SQL Query issued to database : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:22 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:22 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8158    

*****START LOAD SESSION*****

Load Start Time: Tue Dec 17 09:50:22 2019

Target tables:

     MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE


INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    RR_4050 RR_4050 First row returned from database to reader : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:23 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_2_1    DBG_21077   DBG_21077 Create joiner cache on master relation : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:23 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_2_1    TE_7212 Increasing [Index Cache] size for transformation [jnr_MARKET_COVER_ORG_EXT] from [178956970] to [178985984].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_2_1    TE_7212 Increasing [Data Cache] size for transformation [jnr_MARKET_COVER_ORG_EXT] from [357913940] to [357915648].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_2_1    CMN_1690    Created new data file [/infa714/Informatica_Linux/server/infa_shared/Cache/PMJNR6767_5_0_397741.dat] and index file [/infa714/Informatica_Linux/server/infa_shared/Cache/PMJNR6767_5_0_397741.idx] for Joiner [jnr_MARKET_COVER_ORG_EXT].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    RR_4050 RR_4050 First row returned from database to reader : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:23 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    BLKR_16019  Read [67277] rows, read [0] error rows for source table [MAKKET_SERVICE_MODE_MASTER] instance name [MAKKET_SERVICE_MODE_MASTER]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    BLKR_16008  Reader run completed.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_2_1    DBG_21214   DBG_21214 Finished joiner cache on master relation : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:23 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_2_1    DBG_21216   Finished transformations for Source Qualifier [SQ_MAKKET_SERVICE_MODE_MASTER]. Total errors [0] 
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:23 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_1_1    DBG_21603   DBG_21603 Open master relation cache for detail joiner : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:23 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16019  Read [621046] rows, read [0] error rows for source table [S_ORG_EXT] instance name [S_ORG_EXT]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_1_1    DBG_21215   DBG_21215 Finished processing detail relation : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:32 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_1_1    CMN_1795    The index cache size that would hold [67277] input rows from the master for [jnr_MARKET_COVER_ORG_EXT], in memory, is [52736] bytes
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_1_1    CMN_1794    The data cache size that would hold [67277] input rows from the master for [jnr_MARKET_COVER_ORG_EXT], in memory, is [206674944] bytes
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   TRANSF_1_1_1    DBG_21216   Finished transformations for Source Qualifier [SQ_S_ORG_EXT]. Total errors [0] 
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8167    Start loading table [MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE] at: Tue Dec 17 09:50:31 2019
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8168    End loading table [MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE] at: Tue Dec 17 09:50:31 2019
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8035    Load complete time: Tue Dec 17 09:50:31 2019

LOAD SUMMARY
============

WRT_8036 Target: MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE (Instance Name: [MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE])
WRT_8044 No data loaded for this target



INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8043    *****END LOAD SESSION*****
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16008  Reader run completed.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8006    Writer run completed.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24031  
***** RUN INFO FOR TGT LOAD ORDER GROUP [1], CONCURRENT SET [1] *****
Thread [READER_1_1_1] created for [the read stage] of partition point [SQ_S_ORG_EXT] has completed.
    Total Run Time = [9.725447] secs
    Total Idle Time = [0.000000] secs
    Busy Percentage = [100.000000]
Thread [TRANSF_1_1_1] created for [the transformation stage] of partition point [SQ_S_ORG_EXT] has completed.
    Total Run Time = [8.698872] secs
    Total Idle Time = [8.597273] secs
    Busy Percentage = [1.167953]
    Transformation-specific statistics for this thread were not accurate enough to report.
Thread [READER_1_2_1] created for [the read stage] of partition point [SQ_MAKKET_SERVICE_MODE_MASTER] has completed.
    Total Run Time = [1.042087] secs
    Total Idle Time = [0.000000] secs
    Busy Percentage = [100.000000]
Thread [TRANSF_1_2_1] created for [the transformation stage] of partition point [SQ_MAKKET_SERVICE_MODE_MASTER] has completed.
    Total Run Time = [0.687992] secs
    Total Idle Time = [0.527125] secs
    Busy Percentage = [23.382139]
    Transformation-specific statistics for this thread were not accurate enough to report.
Thread [WRITER_1_*_1] created for [the write stage] of partition point [MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE] has completed. The total run time was insufficient for any meaningful statistics.

INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24005  PETL_24005 Starting post-session tasks. : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:32 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   POST-SESS   PETL_24091  Thread [POST-SESS] has the ID [10].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24029  PETL_24029 Post-session task completed successfully. : (Tue Dec 17 09:50:32 2019)
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   MAPPING TM_6018 The session completed with [0] row transformation errors. 
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER TE_7216 Deleting cache files [/infa714/Informatica_Linux/server/infa_shared/Cache/PMJNR6767_5_0_397741.dat] for transformation [jnr_MARKET_COVER_ORG_EXT].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER TE_7216 Deleting cache files [/infa714/Informatica_Linux/server/infa_shared/Cache/PMJNR6767_5_0_397741.idx] for transformation [jnr_MARKET_COVER_ORG_EXT].
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   MANAGER PETL_24002  Parallel Pipeline Engine finished.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    PETL_24012  Session run completed successfully.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6022 

SESSION LOAD SUMMARY
================================================

INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6252 Source Load Summary.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    CMN_1740    Table: [SQ_S_ORG_EXT] (Instance Name: [SQ_S_ORG_EXT])
     Output Rows [621046], Affected Rows [621046], Applied Rows [621046], Rejected Rows [0]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    CMN_1740    Table: [SQ_MAKKET_SERVICE_MODE_MASTER] (Instance Name: [SQ_MAKKET_SERVICE_MODE_MASTER])
     Output Rows [67277], Affected Rows [67277], Applied Rows [67277], Rejected Rows [0]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6253 Target Load Summary.
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    CMN_1740    Table: [MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE] (Instance Name: [MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE])
     Output Rows [0], Affected Rows [0], Applied Rows [0], Rejected Rows [0]
INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6023 
===================================================

INFO    17-12-2019 09:50:32 AM  node01_prdeim   DIRECTOR    TM_6020 Session [s_m_MASTRA_MARKET_COVERAGE_LOAD] completed at [Tue Dec 17 09:50:32 2019].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possibilities - 
 1. May be main reason - Joiner is not producing any data. Have you cheked when you join  Source 1 and Source 2 they are joined on correct key column(s). chances are the data from both system arent matching. Sometime there can be space/special characters in the data and they can cause mismatch. Debug to figure out the reason.
 2. If above reason is not the cause, please check if you set one or more columns as primary key in target. This helps on update part.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.. Actually I missed checking the key relation between update strategy and target instance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @koushik check for joiner first then the key in TGT. Also check the the DD_UPDATE part in your UPD Transformation.